# isset() function always returns true

Tags: php, html, web, isset

I've been figuring out how to do this but it seems not to be working.

My code for the form:

```
<form name="register" method="POST" action="php\reg.php">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email"/>
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

Code for the "reg.php" file:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    echo "success!";
} else {
    echo "empty!";
}
?>
```

Problem is, whenever I input or not in the email textbox, isset function always returns the true value. how can I resolve this??

Comment: If you *submit* the form, then yes, `$_POST['email']` will always be *set*. Whether its value is an empty string or not is a different topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All answers that tell you about using `isset()` and `empty()` to check form values are... bad. Use one of the [**filter functions**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) to check if a POST/GET/COOKIE variable is present and validate or sanitize it. Here is an example:

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($email === NULL) {
    die("Email field not present in form");
} elseif ($email === FALSE) {
    die("Email is present but its value is invalid");
}
```

---

Note: the `empty()` function has a gotcha and I would not recommend using it for form validation unless you understand exactly what it does: it returns true for all *falsy* values. This means `0` is considered *empty* which is often an acceptable value in certain cases. Example (bad one):

```
if (empty($_POST["number_of_children"])) {
    // triggers even when user enters 0
    die("number of children field is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`isset()` checks if the values is set, so it's true even if the value is empty string. Use `empty()`:

```
if (empty($_POST['email']) == false) {
  echo "success!";
}else{
  echo "empty!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
echo "success!";
}else{
echo "empty!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
  echo "success!";
}else{
  echo "empty!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Null and/or empty strings are still set if the variable is declared.

$_POST contains empty string for your value, and isset() returns true. Use empty() or add != '' in your if condition.try this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) function to check if there is anything in email filed of $_POST array.
The example code based on your code is below:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    echo "success!";
} else {
    echo "empty!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `isset` and `empty` together, that's pointless. Just `!empty` will do just fine here.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != "") {
 echo "success!";
 }else{
 echo "empty!";
 }
 ?>
```

try this way